# Inspecting Command History in Emacs Buffer

Tags: emacs, slime

I am wondering if there is any way to inspect all commands stored in the Emacs history. That is, suppose I am using SLIME for Common Lisp development. In SLIME's REPL, I can press `M-p` and `M-n` to navigate through command history.

Quite often, the history becomes extensive, and one would like to easily access commands from much earlier. What is a way to achieve that? What is the most optimal way to achieve that aside from scrolling through commands or through the buffer?

Comment: `M-x command-history` shows you the history as stored in the variable `command-history`. Use `x` to repeat the command at point.

Comment: This shows Emacs mini-buffer commands. What I am after are the Common Lisp commands that were executed at the REPL.

Comment: Ok, I thought by "Emacs history" you meant the minibuffer. I don't think SLIME has a command to search history. If you can try Sly instead, it lets you search the history with the regular isearch keybindings (`C-r`, `C-s`).

Comment: Thanks. I will check out Sly. The way I imagine it, it would be useful to have a one-to-one correspondence between the counter on the REPL prompt and the command history displayed in a visual way in a separate buffer. This works for when one forgets what to search for and is interested in a general clump of commands from the past.

Comment: SLIME seems to store the history in a variable `slime-repl-input-history`. You could write a small mode to browse that.

Comment: https://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Input-Navigation.html

Comment: [helm-slime](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-slime) lets you see the whole history and filter it.

Answer (score 3):

helm is awesome for a lot of tasks, concerning history there are these commands:

```
helm-eshell-history
helm-projects-history
helm-minibuffer-history
helm-reset-adaptive-history
helm-complex-command-history
```

In peculiar I use `M-x helm-complex-command-history` quite often. I hope that you can use these commands in your context.

---

**Extra notes:**

Not directly related to your problem, but maybe useful.

- helm:

If you do not use helm yet you can start by rebinding `M-x` by `helm-M-x` and `C-x b` by `helm-buffers-list`

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") 'helm-buffers-list)
```

to see how it is helpful.

- configuration (history stored between sessions)

You can store extra history and reuse it even if you restart Emacs by putting something like:

```
(savehist-mode 1)
(setq savehist-additional-variables 
      '(compile-command kill-ring search-ring regexp-search-ring))
```

in your **.emacs** file.

Comment: So, [helm-slime](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-slime) ! (not in MELPA)

Comment: @Ehvince Great! helm everywhere! :-)